# Relocating three stray cats

Tags: cats, strays

I'm trying to relocate three stray cats from an apartment complex that I used to stay in earlier. It's one mama cat and her two kittens. The kittens are about 4 months old now. I was thinking of bringing them to my new apartment complex and setting them free here. I cannot take them inside my house since I already have a cat and he isn't too friendly with other cats. I was planning on feeding them so that they wouldn't lose their way and hang around here. I wanted to get the mama cat neutered anyway but I'm wondering if the two kittens who I'm told are always with her would feel completely out of place in their new surroundings. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Is the new complex near to the old one, so that it is possible that they walk home?

Comment: @HarasBrummi nope. They are quite far.